# XML unmarshalling using Jaxb with namespaces and schema

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, jaxb

I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:msgdata xmlns:xs="http://www.myCompany.com" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.myCompany.com msgdata.xsd">
  <xs:msgid>MsgID001</xs:msgid>
  <xs:msgHash>hlkJKLHljkhkjlHKJLHkjl6y987HJKH</xs:msgHash> 
</xs:msgdata>
```

A schema document (called msgdata.xsd) was also sent to me. I am using JAXB to unmarshall the above xml document to a Java object. 
The unmarshalling code is shown below:

```
final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("C:\\temp\\msgdata.xsd"));

final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);

return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
```

The target object for the XML is shown below (The object is then converted to a hibernated entity.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "msgdata")
public class Message {

    private     String  msgid;
    private     String  msgHash;

    @XmlElement(name = "msgid")
    public String getMsgid() {
        return msgid;
    }

    public void setMsgid(String msgid) {
        this.msgid = msgid;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "msgHash")
    public String getMsgHash() {
        return msgHash;
    }
    public void setMsgHash(String msgHash) {
        this.msgHash = msgHash;
    }
```

A couple of questions:

- I have a rest service where i will receive an XML document in the format shown above. What is the reference for the schema document. I know that the schema document is used for validating the XML document. I think the way it will work is that i use that schema to validate the XML documents that i receive via the REST service. Now the problem is how do i access the schema? Do i just store it somewhere on my file system and access it as shown above?

The XML document has a reference to the schema (See the schemaLocation entry). How will it find the schema document on my file system? Is that schema reference required in the XML document?

- The XML document as it is now cannot be unmarshalled. When i try to unmarshal it i get the following error:

  > Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element
  >   (uri:"http://www.myCompany.com", local:"msgdata"). Expected elements
  >   are <{}msgdata>
  >           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:662)
  >   [jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar:]
  >           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:258)
  >   [jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar:]
  >           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:253)
  >   [jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar:]
  >           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:120)
  >   [jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar:]
  >           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1063)
  >   [jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar:]
  >           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:498)
  >   [jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar:]
  >           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:480)
  >   [jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar:]
  >           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:102)
  >   [jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar:]
  >           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:150)
  >   [jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar:]
  >           at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown
  >   Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:]
  >           at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown
  >   Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:]
  >           at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown
  >   Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:]
  >           at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown
  >   Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:]
  >           at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
  >   Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:]
  >           at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:]
  >           at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:]
  >           at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:]
  >           at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:]
  >           at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
  >   Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:]
  >           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:217)
  >   [jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar:]
  >           at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
  >   [jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar:]
  >           at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:136)
  >   [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
  >           at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:193)
  >   [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
  >           ... 31 more

I thought the namespace is defined in the xml document. I am either not using the schema correctly or the namespace definition is not correct. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The following may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html and http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Comment: Does the schema put the elements in the namespaces you're expecting? Post the schema if you want ;]

Comment: I am using JAXB to unmarshall the xml i.e. convert from XML to a java object not the other way round. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, for how to access files (XSD or others) in your Java web application (since you mentioned REST), you could start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream). Never rely on absolute paths, for deployment as well as security reasons.

The xsi schema location attributes are just hints; they are not required. Even if present those don't have to be considered. For a server side application, I would never use them anyway; one should rely on embedded resources, or use a catalog-like concept at a trusted/secure location.

The fact that it doesn't unmarshal, is clear in the error message: it expects a no-namespace element <{}msgdata> as opposed to <{http://www.myCompany.com}msgdata>.

You need to modify the XML or ammend your class to include things like @XmlElement(name="...", namespace="http://www.myCompany.com")

I would say that given schema and XML are correct, your annotations are not in sync.

Comment: Do i need to specify the namespace with the annotations?

Comment: Yes, please use @ XmlElement or @ XmlRootElement with name and namespace: (name="...", namespace="http://www.myCompany.com")

Comment: I tried that and it looks like i need to specify the namespace on each field as well. Is there any way i can specify the namespace globally?

Comment: I would use the [@XmlSchema](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html) annotation at the package level. It would look like this: @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace="http://www.myCompany.com",      elementFormDefault=javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) package com.mypackage;